# How do I add these additional constraints to my retail product/shopping Z3 spec?

Tags: z3

So I created a basic Z3 spec to guide me in buying some specific retail products. So far all it can do is arbitrarily tell me what to buy without exceeding my available funds:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Retailer FooMart BazTrading)))
(declare-datatypes () ((Cartridge .223Rem .7.62x39mm)))
(declare-datatypes () ((Casing Brass Steel)))
(declare-datatypes () ((Offer (Offer
  (getRetailer      Retailer)
  (getCartridge     Cartridge)
  (getRounds        Int)       ; # of rounds
  (getPrice         Int)       ; price in cents
  (getCasing        Casing)
  (getQuantityAvail Int)
))))

(declare-const x1 Offer)
(declare-const x2 Offer)
(declare-const x3 Offer)
(declare-const x4 Offer)
(declare-const x5 Offer)

(assert (= x1 (Offer FooMart    .223Rem    1000 17000 Steel 50)))
(assert (= x2 (Offer BazTrading .223Rem    500  13000 Brass 10)))
(assert (= x3 (Offer FooMart    .7.62x39mm 1000 18000 Steel 15)))
(assert (= x4 (Offer BazTrading .7.62x39mm 100  1850  Steel 20)))
(assert (= x5 (Offer BazTrading .7.62x39mm 20   190   Steel 20)))

; the quantity purchased of each offer/product will be
; between 0 and the max quantity of the offer

(declare-const x1Qty Int)
(assert (>= x1Qty 0))
(assert (<= x1Qty (getQuantityAvail x1)))

(declare-const x2Qty Int)
(assert (>= x2Qty 0))
(assert (<= x2Qty (getQuantityAvail x2)))

(declare-const x3Qty Int)
(assert (>= x3Qty 0))
(assert (<= x3Qty (getQuantityAvail x3)))

(declare-const x4Qty Int)
(assert (>= x4Qty 0))
(assert (<= x4Qty (getQuantityAvail x4)))

(declare-const x5Qty Int)
(assert (>= x5Qty 0))
(assert (<= x5Qty (getQuantityAvail x5)))

; let's say i've got $500 to spend
(declare-const moneyToSpend Int)
(assert (= moneyToSpend 50000))

(declare-const amountSpent Int)
(assert (= amountSpent
  (+ (* x1Qty (getPrice x1))
     (* x2Qty (getPrice x2))
     (* x3Qty (getPrice x3))
     (* x4Qty (getPrice x4))
     (* x5Qty (getPrice x5)))
))
(assert (< amountSpent moneyToSpend))

(maximize amountSpent)
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

https://rise4fun.com/Z3/WxQNw

At this point what I'd like to do is add additional assertions for when I only want to buy `Brass` cased cartridges, or if I only need a specific type of cartridge like `.223Rem`, or add in shipping calculations for each `Retailer` plus a $/round calculation with `minimize` constraint so that I'm not wasting money on shipping, or taking into account volume pricing discounts that certain Offers have (e.g. buy 5 or more, save $0.10/ea, buy 10 or more, save $0.15/ea).

The problem I have is that I feel like the solutions I came up with for these are repetitious and not very elegant and I feel like I'm missing something... particularly since it seems like I'm carrying a lot of overhead myself tracking the relationship between each `xQty` and the `Offer` it corresponds to.

For example, a solution to filtering on only `Brass` casings could be like this:

```
; non-Brass casings get set to qty 0
(assert (if (= (getCasing x1) Brass)
            (>= x1Qty 0)
            (=  x1Qty 0)))

(assert (if (= (getCasing x2) Brass)
            (>= x2Qty 0)
            (=  x2Qty 0)))

; ... etc.
```

Maybe a better example would be trying to implement volume discounts. Say if I wanted to capture volume discounts for offer `x1`:

```
; at this point i'm hardcoding prices in a bag-on-the-side
; function instead of in the x1 Offer itself :/
(define-fun x1Pricing ((qty Int)) Int
  (if (>= 10 qty)
      (* qty 16500)
      (if (>= 5 qty)
          (* qty 16800)
          (* qty (getPrice x1))))
)

(declare-const amountSpent Int)
(assert (= amountSpent
  (+ (x1Pricing x1Qty)
     (* x2Qty (getPrice x2))
     (* x3Qty (getPrice x3))
     (* x4Qty (getPrice x4))
     (* x5Qty (getPrice x5)))
))
(assert (< amountSpent moneyToSpend))
```

It just feels like things are very disparate and I'm wondering if they need to be. Like is there a way for `x1Pricing` to be part of the `Offer` data type, and if so is that even a good way to do it?

My instinct is also to be putting things in lists and mapping over them or something; but while I see z3 has a native List implementation I couldn't grok how to use it or if it would be appropriate (writing `assert`s using `select` with specific index numbers seemed just as cumbersome as having totally separate constants).

So my question is, is there a more optimal way to be doing what I'm trying to do?

From some Z3Py examples I've seen it appears I could reduce some repetition by using Python list comprehensions and correlating things based on index, but I'm also wondering if I'm missing the big picture here with the direction I'm going. Thank you.

edit: I've added a very dumb/naive shipping cost calculation method and cost per round calculation:

```
(declare-const shippingCost Int)
(assert (= shippingCost
  ; FooMart charges a flat $75 shipping fee
  (+ (if (or (= (getRetailer x1) FooMart)
             (= (getRetailer x2) FooMart)
             (= (getRetailer x3) FooMart)
             (= (getRetailer x4) FooMart)
             (= (getRetailer x5) FooMart))
         7500
         0
     )
  ; BazTrading charges a flat $20 + $5 per 100 rounds
     (if (or (= (getRetailer x1) BazTrading)
             (= (getRetailer x2) BazTrading)
             (= (getRetailer x3) BazTrading)
             (= (getRetailer x4) BazTrading)
             (= (getRetailer x5) BazTrading))
         2000
         0
     )
     (* (/ (+ (if (= (getRetailer x1) BazTrading)
                  (getRounds x1)
                  0)
              (if (= (getRetailer x2) BazTrading)
                  (getRounds x2)
                  0)
              (if (= (getRetailer x3) BazTrading)
                  (getRounds x3)
                  0)
              (if (= (getRetailer x4) BazTrading)
                  (getRounds x4)
                  0)
              (if (= (getRetailer x5) BazTrading)
                  (getRounds x5)
                  0))
            100)
        500)
     )
  ))

(declare-const amountSpent Int)
(assert (= amountSpent
  (+ (x1Pricing x1Qty)
     (* x2Qty (getPrice x2))
     (* x3Qty (getPrice x3))
     (* x4Qty (getPrice x4))
     (* x5Qty (getPrice x5))
     shippingCost)))
(assert (< amountSpent moneyToSpend))

(declare-const totalRounds Int)
(assert (= totalRounds
  (+ (* x1Qty (getRounds x1))
     (* x2Qty (getRounds x2))
     (* x3Qty (getRounds x3))
     (* x4Qty (getRounds x4))
     (* x5Qty (getRounds x5)))
))

(declare-const amountSpentPerRound Real)
(assert (= amountSpentPerRound
  (div amountSpent totalRounds)
))

(assert (> amountSpent 20000))
(assert (< amountSpent 30000))
(minimize amountSpentPerRound)
```

https://rise4fun.com/Z3/vEpa3

(Note the model is not satisfiable in the rise4fun online editor but works fine on my local machine using the latest Z3 source)

Now I really think I'm doing something wrong as `shippingCost` is always 12600. When I fiddle with the `amountSpent` max and min value assertions to try to push it into using only BazTrading or FooMart Offers (to bring shipping cost down), it hangs for several minutes before I kill it.

Comment: You may want to see whether this kind of problem can be expressed in the MiniZinc language, which is very high-level. In such a case, you can still generate an SMT-LIB encoding of your problem starting from the MiniZinc model using OptiMathSAT. The generated SMT-LIB formula can be solved using z3.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin I very much appreciate the pointer Patrick. I'm not even particular about needing to use Z3, it just seemed like a popular choice for constraint solving after some googling. MiniZinc looks great; I'm going to give it a whirl!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTLib is not good for writing such specifications. It should be treated more as an "assembly" language, and should be generated from other tools. This is where the high-level APIs come in, depending on your language of choice. There are high-level bindings from C, C++, Java, Python, Haskell, Scala.. You essentially should use those APIs to generate the constraints and use z3 via the API. Each binding has its own advantages/disadvantages, so I'd recommend starting with whatever host language you are most familiar with and use that.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll rewrite in a higher level binding and come back if I still have questions.